# IE6 on 64bit Windows 7

Tags: html, css, windows-7, 64-bit, internet-explorer-6

I am a beginner HTML/CSS coder and I have noticed that the most problematic browser is IE6. Now I want to install IE6 on my computer, to be able to perform live test, but when I try to install IE6 a notification appears saying that it's not possible to install IE6 on 64bit.
Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: I doubt it if anywone is using IE6 anymore!

Comment: Find out if your audience is really using IE6 any more. Most people have abandoned it ages ago. Even IE7 is a minority these days. You save *countless* hours by ignoring IE6 completely, and rather make your page work decently in IE7. And since you're a beginner in HTML/CSS, you should learn the new and coming stuff, not how to hack your code to work half-well in an outdated browser.

Comment: It is possible to install IE6 on x64; it's just not possible to install it on Windows Vista or Windows7. Your best bet is to look at either using a VirtualMachine in which you can install Windows XP + IE6, or use some other testing framework to help you identify problems in your code that IE6 will not support. Bear in mind that IE6 is now end-of-lifed by Microsoft, so unless you've got a good reason to support it (i.e. your customer is paying extra because they need it), I'd not bother. Running IE6 on the real-life internets really is as stupid as your PIN number on the back of your card.

Comment: @SecurityMatt tell that to the bank and insurance companies, using to-IE-built-in applications, I bet there are still some requiring IE6 to this day and a lot more requiring IE in general (not edge). It's sad I know.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

[IETester](http://www.debugbar.com)

You get a pseudo IE version emulation, instead of installing (downgrading) IE version

Answer (score 3):

You will need a virtual machine. I know microsoft hosts a version themself. Right now the link isn't working for me but you might want to try this: 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en%3e&id=11575

Also if you have an old windows xp disk you can just install [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
And then install Windows XP on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not directly an answer to your question but if you want to test various different Internet Explorer versions you may use a tool like IE Tester:

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

You may test IE5.5 up to 10 with this single application.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provide virtual machines for testing specific versions of Internet Explorer. [This page has all the links and information you need](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&amp;displaylang=e&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 1):

You could start off by writing one simple Selenium script and test your website immediately in all browsers.
For example on http://testingbot.com you can run your browser test on all browsers at once.

This way you're not only testing ancient browsers, but also the newer ones.

Answer (score 0):

ie6 is dying and almost dead... meanwhile, you can maybe install virtual xp machine and get ie6 there for test...

also, there's [Adobe browser lab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html) with all existing browsers...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother setting up a VM, you can use a service like Sauce Lab's scout. It's free service, though you have to register an account. I've used it for quick testing of designs on older browsers:

https://saucelabs.com/docs/scout/getting-started

(It actually spins up a VM in the cloud and gives you limited remote control).

Answer (score 0):

There's a VirtualBox image with Internet Explorer 6 in it available here:

http://www.npackd.org/p/xp-ie6-virtualbox/2014.10.27

You can download VirtualBox here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

[image]